# Database design for like/love relations

Tags: database, database-design

I know this might have been asked quite a few times, however I can not find any suitable solution for my problem.
I am implementing database where I have users and articles.
Now the article can be either liked or loved by any of the user.
And here comes the problem, I have to return json that contains list of all articles extended by two fields, liked  and loved, because queries are gonna be connected to users.
So liked and loved might be true or false.
I thought about creating two different tables Liked & Loved where I would keep article_id - user_id  and if that record exists that means user liked/loved particular article. However I am not quite sure if thats the correct way, nor I have any idea how would I build such query. 
If it is important I am using postgresql together with ormlite.
Thanks for any ideas.

Comment: Is it possible for the same article to be both liked and loved by the same user?

Comment: OK, then you'd need a junction table with two flags: one for "like" the other for "love" (and a CHECK to ensure at least one of them is non-NULL). Essentially the same thing was already proposed by @Cratylus.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I have understand your question you are basically describing an M-N relationship. A user likes/loves N articles and an article is liked/loved by M users. Such relationships are implemented via a third table that stores the association of users and articles.
You could create a table UserPreferences that links user_id and article_id and has extra columns to indicate if he liked/loved the article.
I can't tell you more about the schema since I don't know if you have other degrees about the preferences (hated, indifferent, confused etc)

Comment: So you basically say that I could to it like, third table where I have article_id - user_id - liked - loved  and then when I am quering I should join those relations. That makes sense :) thanks for that idea